# How to check if View is empty with PHP

Tags: 7, views

I'm using [Simplenews Scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews_scheduler) to automatically send a digest of new nodes, by inserting a views token into Body field of the newsletter.

I need to prevent sending the newsletter if the View in question is empty (triggers No results).

Simplenews Scheduler allows for PHP evaluation (see at the bottom of the screenshot):

[image: Simplenews Scheduler options]

What do I need to enter there to ensure no new newsletter is created and sent if a certain view (with certain exposed filter or contextual filters options) has no results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will do:

```
!empty(views_get_view_result('your_views_machine_name','your_display_id'));
```

If you need to pass arguments, you can pass them as individual strings after the display id. See the [API documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7). I'm not sure if you can pass exposed filter arguments, though (the above would work fine for contextual filter arguments).

Comment: Thank you! I do need to pass 2 arguments, the first one is a category and the second one is US states list and can be multivalue. My corresponding views token can be: `[view:my_views_machine_name=page_3=$arg1/IL+TX]` Should my code then be `!empty(views_get_view_result('my_views_machine_name','page_3','Category-1','IL+TX'));` ?

Comment: As far as I know the arguments after `display_id` are passed to the view the same way Contextual Filters are passed through the path of the view. Thus, IF your view works fine (and produces the desired results) by calling it through its path as in www.example.com/view_path/Category-1/IL+TX then it should work by using `views_get_view_result()` with CAtegory-1 and IL+TX as the 3rd and 4th arguments.

Comment: I haven't tested it with Scheduler yet, but I did test the PHP in a node body with if - print and it seems to be working, with arguments. Thank you!